# Hiding encryption key on server in Java

Tags: java, key, hide, vps

I'm making a client/server app in Java. I want to run my server on VPS. Is there any way to protect the encryption key (in my case it's a RSA private key) so that the VPS provider cannot mess with it?

Comment: Java not JAVA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can obfuscate it (by encrypting it before you copy it to the VPS and decrypting it in your compiled code). However, if an attacker (or the VPS) is determined enough such mechanisms can be defeated. After all, they have physical access to the raw hardware and you do not.